# Printing the binary value of a number in clojure

Tags: clojure

We can represent the number `12` as `2r001100` in clojure.

Is there a built-in function to print `2r001100` when given the number 12?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

see [cl-format](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.pprint-api.html#clojure.pprint/cl-format)

```
user=> (require '[clojure.pprint :refer (cl-format)])
nil
user=> (cl-format nil "2r~6,'0',B" 12)
"2r001100"
```

Comment: This is great, but will not print the two's complement representation of the number for a negative input.

Answer (score 28):

[java.lang.Integer/toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString(int,%20int)) will print numbers with arbitrary radix:

```
(Integer/toString 0xf2 2)  ==> "11110010"
(Integer/toString 0xf2 16) ==> "f2"
(Integer/toString 0xf2 27) ==> "8q"
```

Comment: If you need the binary representation with leading zeros you can use `(-> 0x7 (Integer/toString 2) (Integer/parseInt) (->> (format "%04d")))` that will result in `0111`.

Answer (score 8):

These functions generate and print strings using [java.util.Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

- [format](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/format)
- [printf](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/printf)

But they don't do binary, so the best I could come up with is:

```
(fn [i] (str "2r" (Integer/toBinaryString i)))
```

Answer (score 4):

All of these answers are good, but either won't support two's-complement for negative numbers (cl-format), or won't print out the correct number of bits based on the width of the data itself (e.g., calling Integer/toBinaryString or Integer/toString on a byte will not do what you want, especially for negative numbers).

Here's a solution that will correctly print out the exact bits of the underlying data:

```
(defn print-bits [b]
  (let [class-name (.getName (class b))
        is-byte (= "java.lang.Byte" class-name)
        num-bits (clojure.lang.Reflector/getStaticField class-name "SIZE")
        format-string (str "~" num-bits "'0b")
        bin-str-fn #(clojure.lang.Reflector/invokeStaticMethod
                     (if is-byte "java.lang.Integer" class-name)
                     "toBinaryString"
                     (to-array [%]))
        bit-string (if is-byte
                     (str/join (take-last 8 (bin-str-fn (Byte/toUnsignedInt b))))
                     (bin-str-fn b))]
    (println (str (str/join (repeat (- num-bits (count bit-string)) \0))
                  bit-string))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Test of extremes here, using `(bit-shift-left 1 63)`, or `1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`.

The `cl-format` solution provided gives me an integer overflow.

`Integer/toBinaryString` gives me `Value out of range for int: -9223372036854775808`.

But `Long/toBinaryString` gives me the string that I expected.